# How to merge and groupby between seperate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I want to merge/groupby. They are below:

```html
df_1


        words      start   stop
0            Oh,    6.72   7.21
1          okay,    7.26   8.01
2             go  12.82   12.90
3         ahead.   12.91  12.94
4             NaN  15.29  15.62
5             NaN  15.63  15.99
6             NaN  16.09  16.36
7             NaN  16.37  16.96
8             NaN  17.88  18.36
9             NaN  18.37  19.36
```

```html
df_2

data     start        stop
10         1.0        3.5
14         4.0       8.5
11         9.0       13.5
12        14.0       20.5
```

I want to merge df_1.words onto df_2, but group all values in df_1.words where df_1.start is in between df_2.start and df_2.stop. It should look like this:

```html
df_2

data     start        stop   words
10         1.0        3.5     NaN
14         4.0       8.5      Oh, okay,
11         9.0       13.5     go ahead.
12        14.0       20.5     NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html?  It's similar to a left join but will match on nearest key rather than strictly equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bin edges do not overlap as in your example, use `pd.cut`, with an `IntervalIndex` to group the first DataFrame. This allows you to be closed on both edges. Then select from with the 'stop' column from `df_2` to get the aggregated result.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.Index([pd.Interval(*x, closed='both') for x in zip(df_2.start, df_2.stop)])

s = df_1.groupby(pd.cut(df_1.start, idx)).words.agg(list)

# Closed on both, can use `'stop'` to align
df_2['words'] = s[df_2.stop].to_list()
```

---

```
print(df_2)
   data  start  stop                           words
0    10    1.0   3.5                              []
1    14    4.0   8.5                    [Oh,, okay,]
2    11    9.0  13.5                    [go, ahead.]
3    12   14.0  20.5  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the two dataframes are not too long, we can do a cross-join:

```
(df2.assign(dummy=1)
    .merge(df.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy',
           how='left', suffixes=['','_r']
          )
    .query('start<=start_r<=stop')
    .groupby(['data','start','stop'],as_index=False)
    .agg({'words':list})
)
```

Output:

```
   data  start  stop                           words
0    11    9.0  13.5                    [go, ahead.]
1    12   14.0  20.5  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
2    14    4.0   8.5                    [Oh,, okay,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
cut=pd.cut(df_1['start'],df_2[['start','stop']].stack())
mapper=df_1.groupby(cut).words.agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)))
mapper.index=mapper.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.left)
df_2['words']=df_2['start'].map(mapper)

print(df_2)

   data  start  stop                    words
0    10    1.0   3.5                         
1    14    4.0   8.5                Oh, okay,
2    11    9.0  13.5                go ahead.
3    12   14.0  20.5  nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

Comment: I was thinking about this. But I had an issue with the fact that `pd.cut` can only have **either** the left, or right bin closed when given a list, not both. So given the non-continuous bins it becomes quite problematic as to what happens when there are times that coincide with both edges, like 1.0 and 8.5. Granted my solution fails when the edges overlap and then this is preferable :D